# start-stop-daemon not removing old pid file

Tags: 14.04, services, init.d

I have an init script that I've written to start and stop an application as a service. Code is here:

```
#! /bin/bash
PID_FILE=/var/run/myservice.pid
case "$1" in
  start)
      echo "Starting up MyService..."
      start-stop-daemon --start -b -m --pidfile $PID_FILE --exec /usr/bin/java -- -cp /path/to/jarfile.jar $CLASS_NAME --config /etc/myService/config.ini
      cat $PID_FILE
    ;;
  stop)
     echo "Stopping MyService..."
     start-stop-daemon --stop --signal KILL -b -m --pidfile $PID_FILE --exec /usr/bin/java -- -cp /path/to/jarfile.jar $CLASS_NAME --config /etc/myService/config.ini
    ;;
  status)
    start-stop-daemon --status --pidfile $PID_FILE
    PROC_STATUS=$?
    echo $PROC_STATUS
    exit $PROC_STATUS
    ;;
esac
```

The service starts and stops fine, but the behaviour I'm noticing is that when I run

```
sudo service MyService stop
```

the pid file is not removed. When I try to start or restart the service, this is successful - it just writes the new pid to the pid file. Why isn't the pid file removed when the service is properly stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `start-stop-daemon` is not supposed to remove pidfiles. You can do it in your script (`rm -f $pidfile`). You might want to take a look at some other start script. The script `/etc/init.d/dbus` for example has the following shutdown script (for do `stop`):

```
shut_it_down()
{
  log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
  start-stop-daemon --stop --retry 5 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE \
    --user $DAEMONUSER
  # We no longer include these arguments so that start-stop-daemon
  # can do its job even given that we may have been upgraded.
  # We rely on the pidfile being sanely managed
  # --exec $DAEMON -- --system $PARAMS
  log_end_msg $?
  rm -f $PIDFILE
}
```

From the manual page:

> -m, --make-pidfile
>                 Used when starting a program that does not create  its  own  pid
>                 file.  This  option  will make start-stop-daemon create the file
>                 referenced with --pidfile and place the pid into it just  before
>                 executing  the  process. Note, the file will not be removed when
>                 stopping the program.  NOTE: This feature may not  work  in  all
>                 cases.  Most  notably when the program being executed forks from
>                 its main process. Because of this, it  is  usually  only  useful
>                 when combined with the --background option.

(see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it would not remove old PID files. I'll just add the `rm -f $PID_FILE`.